# See Full Weight

Tags: weight-painting

Is there a way to see the weight of the entire model rather than selecting each bone?

Id like to do this so I can see what vertices have not been assigned.

Cheers!

Comment: Weigh of a vertex is a per-bone value. How would you visualize weights for more than one bone at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

To check if any vertices have the wrong weight assigned to them I recommend posing the Armature. Simply go into Pose Mode and pose the model to some often used pose.
That way you will see the deformations on the model and it will be easier to spot wrong weights. Once you start adding weight to vertices they will automatically move to fit the pose.

Comment: To elaborate on this, to find unweighted vertices, I usually just translate the root bone a large amount.